# working from command prompt but not from IDLE GUI in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

`import tabulate` is working from command prompt, but not from IDLE GUI in python 2.7
from IDLE GUI I'm gettng the following error :

```
ImportError: No module named tabulate
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
from tabulate import tabulate
```

Comment: Did you install it using pip?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate
you might have installed the command line utility.
Now install the library using pip,then it will work on IDLE